# When condition with similarity

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to use 2 similar conditions with the like operator as shown in the code below, but all cases are falling on the first one and coming back 3, there's no case coming back with 7, but when I validate the source file they exist.

What am I doing wrong with the condition?

```
df_plugin_type = df_plugin.withColumn('sk_channel',
                                              when(lower(col('Type')).contains('onsitemessage') & lower(col('AdditionalData')).like("%22:1%"), lit(3))
                                              .when(lower(col('Type')).contains('onsitemessage') & lower(col('AdditionalData')).like("%22:2%"), lit(7))
                                              .when(lower(col('Type')).contains('lightbox'), lit(4))
                                              .when(lower(col('Type')).contains('pushoptin'), lit(8))) \
            .filter(col('sk_channel').isNotNull())
```

Comment: Could you add sample data + expected output? currently its hard to say what the issue is

Comment: @ScootCork https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72116775/when-condition-in-pyspark-with-an-equal-column I make the question again, with dataframes and expected output.